# Mouse acceleration-esque issues

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, mouse

lately I've been noticing an issue while playing CS:GO that feels like mouse acceleration. Not sure if this is a new issue or if I've never noticed, but my view seems to move slightly further when I move the mouse fast compared to moving the mouse slow.

Here's a video, I'm moving the mouse inside a confined space (about 30cm), faster when moving left, slower when moving right. I've already checked and mouse acceleration in windows is disabled (MouseThreshold1 and MouseThreshold2 are 0) and it's disabled ingame as well.

I'm left wondering if I'd need to get a new mouse to test if it's a problem with the sensor, it's a Logitech G700 at 1600DPI with 1000/500Hz polling rate on Windows 10.

edit: I've never fully fixed the problem with that particular mouse, I feel like something was up with the sensor.

Comment: If the acceleration is off in the game settings and also in the windows settings there could be possible a setting in your driver software (its actually unlikly, but you can never know). You also should try to set the raw input in the game settings to on.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Logitech G700 is a laser mouse. All lasers (except latest models) have uncontrollable built-in mouse acceleration. You can do nothing about it.

Comment: "All lasers (except latest models) have uncontrollable built-in mouse acceleration." Citation needed. "As far as I know" Please check and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Please try setting off mouse enchantments in Windows control panel, go to your mouse driver and set acceleration off, also disable acceleration in CS:GO and use **m_rawinput 1**.